# Не отправляется DELETE запрос на сервер через jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js

Я делаю:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8001/admin/clothes/delete',
        method: "DELETE",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('data');
        }
    });
```

А в консоли ошибка:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Запрос идет на мой node js сервер, где я указал

```
response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Но ошибка все равно выдается, пробовал с GET запросом, там все нормально.

Comment: А обработка `OPTIONS` метода на серваке есть?

Comment: Проще в настройках сервера разрешить мультидоменные запросы.

Comment: @Suvitruf нет, а как сделать?

Comment: Сделал OPTIONS на сервере, но все равно ошибка, только другая, которую я убрал добавив заголовки но вернулся к той которая и была. Если делать запрос OPTIONS то зачем вообще PUT/DELETE? Мне 2 запрос надо делать разных. При это судя по network результат выдается, но в консоли 2 ошибки 404 и 1 которая выше + 404

Comment: Браузер автоматически посылает OPTIONS запрос для проверки. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Да, теперь работает. Спасибо

Comment: Рад, что помогло ^_^